# Esbuild with ReactJS.NET?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs.net, esbuild

**TL;DR** How can I use [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) with [ReactJS.NET](https://reactjs.net/bundling/webpack.html#for-existing-projects)?

---

**Long version**

ReactJS.NET expects the following from a "bundle":

```
React.Exceptions.ReactNotInitialisedException: 'React has not been loaded correctly: missing (React, ReactDOM, ReactDOMServer). Please expose your version of React as global variables named 'React', 'ReactDOM', and 'ReactDOMServer'
```

What Webpack actually does is always quite unclear to me, but looking at the ReactJS.NET Webpack tutorial [here](https://reactjs.net/bundling/webpack.html#for-existing-projects), this is the setup:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import RootComponent from './home.jsx';

global.React = React;
global.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
global.ReactDOMServer = ReactDOMServer;

global.Components = { RootComponent };
```

Further at the sample webpack-config [here](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/blob/main/src/React.Template/reactnet-webpack/webpack.config.js), there is this output-setting:

```
{
  [...]
  globalObject: 'this',
}
```

Mirroring this in esbuild would be using `iife` and `esbuild.globalName = 'this'`, but it throws an error:

```
 > (global name):1:0: error: Expected identifier but found "this"
    1 │ this
```

Esbuild is quite stern on that it is a bundler (not a transpile-and-concatenator), so how would I tweak Esbuild to have the bundle mutate the `global` object to what React.NET expects? - And is it even possible?

Thanks,
Flemming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```js
import { build } from 'esbuild'

const globalName = 'whatever'

build({
    [...]
    format: 'iife',
    globalName,
    footer: {
        // Important! Assigns the raw export of the bundle to whatever `this` is in the given context
        js: `Object.assign(this, ${globalName})`,
    },
})
```